# Can I initialize values for php combobox in model file?

Tags: php, cakephp, combobox

I am editing someone else code and I need to make as little changes as possible.I am trying to add a combo box for the subject line in the contact form.

This is the **model** php file for the contact form.  How can I initialize the combo box values? Do I even do that here or should I try to do that in the corresponding ctp file? Note that it has to be php - no html files here.

```
class AbstractContact extends CmsAppModel
{
    var $name = 'Contact';
    var $useTable = false;
    var $_schema = array(
    'name'      =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100), 
My code =>  'subject'   =>array('type'=>'string', 'length'=>100),
    'message'   =>array('type'=>'text'),
    );

var $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        'required' => true, 
        'rule'=>VALID_NOT_EMPTY, 
        'message'=>'Name is required'),

    'message' => array(
        'required' => true, 
        'rule'=>VALID_NOT_EMPTY, 
        'message'=>'Message is required')
);

var $fieldProperties = array(
        'name' =>array(
        'type'=>'text',
        'group'=>'contact'
        ),
My code =>        'subject'=>array(
        'type'=>'select',
        'group'=>'contact'
        ),      
        'message'=>array(
        'type'=>'textarea',
        'group'=>'contact'
        )   
    );
}

?>
```

Comment: Do that for the input form field itself in the ctp. That requires the least changes.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I found that if I do  'topic'=>array(
    'type'=>'select',
                                'options' => array("General", "Technical Support", "Advertising", "Abuse"),'empty' => '(choose one)', 'group'=>'contact'
    ), it works. But I would rather not modify the model file. If i do it in ctp via echo $form->input(..) the combo box appears as the last item on the form which is not very logical.